# Search JSON Array based on variable?

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a JSON Array that I need to search:

```
[
{
      "Device_ID":"1",
      "Image":"HTC-One-X.png",
      "Manufacturer":"HTC",
      "Model":"One X",
      "Region":"GSM",
      "Type":"Phone"
   },
   {
      "Device_ID":"2",
      "Image":"Motorola-Xoom.png",
      "Manufacturer":"Motorola",
      "Model":"Xoom",
      "Region":"CDMA",
      "Type":"Tablet"
   },
   {
      "Device_ID":"8",
      "Image":"null",
      "Manufacturer":"Motorola",
      "Model":"Xoom 2",
      "Region":"CDMA",
      "Type":"Tablet"
   }
]
```

Using the keyword: `$_GET['keyword'];` I need to be able to do the following.
Search the combined value of Manufacturer and Model, ie. Motorola Xoom.  Then, for whichever set of values matches this, output them to variables.

For example:  If the Keyword was HTC, then it would search the array and output:

```
$DeviceID = 1 $Image = HTC-One-X.png $Manufacturer = HTC $Model = One
X $Region = GSM $Type = Type
```

However if the keyword was Motorola, then it would need to output all entries that include Motorola.

What im trying to do, is output a live view of all JSON Array entries, as the user types the keyword.  However I want this to run on the users computer to reduce the load on the server.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

Comment: you'll have to use javascript then.

Comment: oops, not sure why i added php instead of javascript tags.  Sorted that

Comment: And what problem do you have? It seems like you have to iterate over the array and see whether the keyword is in the `Manufacturer` property. I also don't see how this problem is related to JSON apart from the fact that you get the data as JSON (but you don't seems to have a problem *with* JSON).

Comment: Just updated the question.  Basically, wondering how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you have a selection box with the values for the manufacturer in the options section it's as easy as:

HTML:

```
<select id="selectionBox">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
<div id="outPut">
  output goes in here
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("selectionBox").value;
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++){
  if(jsonObject[i].Manufacturer === selectedValue){
    //considering your object is an array let's
    for(var key in jsonObject[i]){
      document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML += jsonObject[i][key] + "</br>";
    }
  }
}
```

that'll pretty much print everything in the object onto the output div, the rest is up to your styling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function for filtering the JSON. Displaying the data is up to you.

```
var devices = <your JSON array>;    

function filter(keyword, data) {
    var filteredArray = [], i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        if ((data[i].Manufacturer && data[i].Manufacturer.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) || (data[i].Model && data[i].Model.indexOf(keyword) !== -1)) {
            filteredArray.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
    return filteredArray;
}

// Example usage
var MotorolaDevices = filter('Motorola', devices);
```